# do lots of links with keywords affect SEO?

Tags: seo, hyperlink, tag-cloud

as you know, some websites have lots of links with keywords in their frontpage. sometimes they use cloudtags and in other cases they even link the "most popular" searches.
do you think that could be a good idea for SEO?

Comment: I think this kind of question belongs on http://doctype.com/ , don't you?

Comment: i think you.re right, next time i'll post this sort of questions there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more links you have the better it is, but remember that search engines developers are not foolish and will try to favorize websites with real interesting content first.

So invest in your content, then in links to your content.